# How to show y axis values with colors in background of a plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, scatter-plot, lattice

Suppose I have this data-set:

```
d <- data.frame("year"=c(2000:2005), "val"=c(rnorm(6,0,1)))
```

I want to show the `val` against `year`, but I don't want line, points or bar plots. Instead, I want to use `val` values showing with stretched colors covering entire background of plot area. Any suggestion?

Comment: I can't picture what you mean.  Like filled rectangles?  Maybe you can find a plot that looks similar and link to it.

Comment: yes, something like filled rectangles.

Comment: For ggplot2 you could get the effect you want by treating year as a factor and using `geom_bar` with `width = 1` or `geom_tile` with a single fake y axis character variable.

Comment: Is this what you want? `ggplot(data=d) + geom_tile(aes(x=year,y=1,fill=val))`

Comment: @aosmith @MikeyMike; thanks for your comments! that's what I wanted, but do you know how I can do this out of ggplot environment?

Comment: Like using base R?

Comment: @MikeyMike that's right

Comment: Much easier and nicer in ggplot but: `barplot(table(d$year),col=colorRampPalette(c('cadetblue1', 'cadetblue4'))(length(d$val))[rank(d$val)])` is a way you can do it in base R. Dark = high values and light = low values.

Comment: @MikeyMike thanks, that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you're describing you have two options:

*Data:* `d <- data.frame("year"=c(2000:2005), "val"=c(rnorm(6,0,1)))`

(1) **Ggplot**

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=d) + geom_tile(aes(x=year,y=1,fill=val))
```

[image]
(2) **Base R**

```
barplot(table(d$year),col=colorRampPalette(c('cadetblue1', 'cadetblue4'))(length(d$val))[rank(d$val)])
```

[image]

In the base R example, Dark = higher values of `d$val` whereas light = lower values of `d$val`.